# Big blank space HTML

Tags: asp.net, html, css

In some area I have this big space between some sentence:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to correct this with CSS?

HTML for a second example:

```
<span style="color: rgb(197, 0, 0); text-align: justify; font-size: 14px;">
    <span id="MainContent_rptTest_lblTitle_2">Support to Efficient, Effictive and Transparent</span><br>
        <div style="color: rgb(197, 0, 0); text-align: justify; font-size: 12px;">
            <strong>
                <span id="MainContent_rptTest_lblDescription_2">September 2009 &ndash; January 2010</span></strong></div>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out the text-align: justify. That's what it does to get the right margin of the text to line up. You can't have both.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the culprit is the css-style: text-align:justify which makes sure that each line of text is the same length

Answer (score -1):

Mess with the [word-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_word-spacing.asp) property.

No guarantees ;)